# Retrieving data from belongsToMany relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have some problems with getting data from my relationship. I need the tags of some domains.

```
$domains = Domains::where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();
```

There are all the domains I need. On my Domains model I have this belongsToMany relation to my pivot table.

```
public function tags() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tags_Domains', 'domain_tag', 'domains_id', 'tags_id'); 
}
```

I was able to get all the datas from my relation with this:

```
dd($domains[0]->tags);
```

That gave me all the data I wanted but only for the very first domain. But I want this for every domain, to pass this new array to my Blade template. I tried many things out but couldn't make it work. ( $collection error, trying to get properly of non-object ... )

Can someone help me there?

---

Controller Code:

```
    $domains = Domains::where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();
    return view('defaultLayout.domains.tagsdelete', [
        'domains' => $domains
    ]);
```

Comment: why you don't just send `$domains` to your blade and then for each domain you show the related tags ? `@foreach($domains as $domain) $domain->tags @endforeach`

Comment: cause I'm getting this : Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$tags

Comment: Show us your controller code.

Comment: I've updated my question with my controller code

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use $domains[0] and you get the first domain.
You must loop through them:

```
foreach($domains as $domain) {
    foreach($domain->tags as $tag) {
        var_dump($tag);
    }
}
```

Edit:
If you need the tags in your view here is how:

```
@foreach($domains as $domain)
     <p>{{ $domain->name }}</p> //where name could be any field that $domain has
     @foreach($domain->tags as $tag)
     <p>{{ $tag->name }}</p> //where name could be any field that $tag has
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Glad I was helpful :)

Comment: I want to pass the name of tags, id of the tags and just the domain names to my view. -- my controller code is in my question and I still haven't did something in my view. Your code worked so far, but I need to save the data in an array and pass that array. Outsite of my foreach, I'm just getting a single data string. Not everything like if I'm var_dump $tag inside of my loop

Comment: yes, I also did it exactly like you in your new update :) workes perfect. I'm still new in laravel, thanks for your support ! :)